# Enable selected word highlight occurrence on Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, highlight, selected

Is there any way to select a word on NetBeans IDE and make it highlighted on all ITS occurrences (like Eclipse IDE)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**First Solution**

Tools->Font & Colors->Syntax

[image]

**Second Solution:**

https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorials/nbm-mark-occurrences.html